# image sensor line problem

Tags: image-sensor

I have an image sensor problem and I am looking everywhere to identify the problem but couldn't. Attached is the problem I observe. As you can see there are several horizontal lines in the image.

[image]

So far, I have checked power, clocks and all seems in order. Appreciate any ideas you may have. (If I get a test image from sensor-diagonal tiles etc-, all seems to be good. So, I am assuming it is not communication with the sensor. Sensor datasheet is [here](http://www.aptina.com/assets/downloadDocument.do?id=844))

I am not looking for a specific answer but more of a direction and/or ideas. Somebody with the right experience could know where to look.

Apparently this type of problems can be observed in other sensors. See the [link](http://www.pentaxforums.com/forums/pentax-dslr-discussion/81147-horizontal-lines-help.html).

I have realized, I missed out one critical information, if I reduce the clock frequency of the sensor the problem disappears. So there is a clock frequency dependency. However I do not suspect read out since if I set the test pattern, regardless of frequency all is good.

**Imager Power Supply Noise figures**

Analog Supply
[image: Analog Supply, AC mode]

Digital Supply
[image: Digital Supply, AC mode]

**UPDATE**

After further testing, I figured the problem is same in every frame. Previously, I was wrong. Here is the 4 images from different times. Images are stiched together, all 480x752

[image]

Comment: I could give you an answer, but it's under NDA. How do you want us to help you if you can't give us information?

Comment: @stevenvh nonconstructive. If you have something good to contribute I am all ears.

Comment: Like I said: we can't help you if you can't help us helping you :-). I understand it's not your fault, but as it stands the question can't be answered IMO. (No I can't answer it either, not even under NDA :-))

Comment: @stevenvh I am hoping this is a common enough problem that somebody with the experience will notice it. I just attached a link with a similar problem.

Comment: Is the pattern of lines the same in every frame, or does it change from frame to frame?

Comment: This is not an inappropriate question.  He may need to give more info but there are several mechanisms that apply to any analog chip that manifest itself in image sensors simply because of read out time.

Comment: Cute inside joke for your handle

Comment: @DaveTweed this is the first thing I checked, they chance from frame to frame.

Comment: @Ktc When you slow down frequency, does it get better gradually or abruptly?  Also, does the pattern change in any particular way when frequency changes?

Comment: @Ktc What operational mode are you using (Simultaneous Master Mode, Sequential Master Mode, etc)?

Comment: @apalopohapa snapshot mode. I only take a picture once in a while.

Comment: @apalopohapa gradually gets better. I need to go back and observe the change in frequency vs pattern. I was out now I will work tonight and report back.

Comment: @DaveTweed Dave you were right, it turns out they are same in every image. See the new photos.

Comment: @apalopohapa I just figured the problem lines are always in same place. What does this mean? Do you have any insights.

Comment: @Ktc this know as column fixed pattern noise.  You'll have to run some image statistics - matlab is good for this.  determine the average and the Std on a given column and also the what the distribution looks like.  BUt you've got a big clue!  you slow it down and it goes away.  the second clue you have is that this is a shipping part and you will be able to find examples of other people that have run the part without noise.  You have a board layout issue.  If you had used the serial port this issue _Probably_ would be less.

Comment: I also encountered this issue with snapshot mode, but the image is good in master mode. Someone said that change simutaneous mode to sequential mode(in chip control register) can solve the problem. It's truly can resolve the noise problem, but the image are still not very clear, which seems to be other exposure and gain issue. It's really frustrating.

Comment: @Won we have tried everything we can think of and it is not been possible to solve this issue. We tried the sequential bit already but not a big improvement. Let me know if you make progress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the pattern of the column is the same whenever they appear, the problem is called [fixed-pattern noise](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-pattern_noise). This is just something you need to deal with, especially when dealing with a raw sensor. The sensor vendor should be able to help with characterizing it.

To deal with it, you can either go through a manual calibration procedure that allows you to derive offset and gain correction factors for each column, which you then store in nonvolatile memory, or you can develop an adaptive algorithm that can recognize and compensate for FPN in live images on the fly.

To characterize the FPN, you'll need to take a series of flat-field images (same amount of light on each pixel) at various light levels (including completely dark) and various exposure times. For each combination of light level and exposure, take the average value of the pixels in each column, and average these values over many frames (to eliminate thermal noise).

From this set of data for each sensor column, you will be able to determine what gain and offset values to apply to that column to eliminate the fixed pattern. You will also be able to determine whether the correction values need to be different for different exposure times, or a common set of values will work well enough for all exposure settings.

You'll also want to do this across a number of individual sensors, to make sure that the statistical variations among sensors don't invalidate the solution you come up with.

Comment: you may be right and it's a good suggestion, but FPN typically manifests itself as first column oriented noise and then pixel by pixel variation (which in the strictest sense is how the term should be used).

Comment: @rawbrawb I am not entirely sure. Here is the real weird thing, I read the frame row by row. So that black lines manifests themselves across every row. So it is not I get a bad row, I get a bad column. Is this FPN? I doubt it.

Comment: @rawbrawb It turns out all images has the same noise pattern, could this be FPN?

Comment: @Ktc The datasheet (thanks for providing the link!) specifically talks about "row-wise noise correction" on page 49. Do you have this feature enabled?

Comment: @DaveTweed Yes, row noise correction has no impact. I think our noise is on columns. If you look at the second image I attached, the images are 90 rotated, so as you can see the noise is on the columns.

Comment: @Ktc Ah, I didn't understand that the second image was rotated. In that case, yes, this is classic FPN, caused by variations in the gain and offset values of the individual column sense amplifiers. Since they (surprisingly) don't deal with this on-chip, you're going to have to make the adjustments in the data yourself.

Comment: @DaveTweed http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/1091/is-this-a-correct-method-for-fixed-pattern-noise-correction is this a recommended solution?

Comment: @Ktc Yes, the [accepted answer](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/1095/1996) is a good start, at least as far as offset calibration. However, as some of the comments mention, it does not take into account gain variations, which can also be significant.

Comment: @DaveTweed is there anything else you can point out going towards fixing this? Much appreciated.

Comment: Dark frame subtraction will only be useful if you can provide a dark frame often as the effect will be temperature dependant.  It would be better to fix the board layout.

Comment: @rawrawb I don't know where the problem is. The supplies look really clean. What I should fix? I am willing to spin another board just to test but not sure on the next course of action.

Answer (score 1):

Can you post the whole image? Looks like bias lines on the CCD. I'm also going to guess it is a high frame rate sensor, because the lines are so noticeable. Are you doing anything else while reading out, or doing anything else with the sensor? I think the timing for each line has to be consistent.

Comment: Sensor is CMOS, global shutter. MT9V032

Comment: I am not doing anything during the read out other than FPGA dumping the data to memory. CPU is active but it is waiting on a flag for frame to be dumped.

Comment: @Ktc - Is the MT9V032 that sensor which is supposed to be under NDA? The datasheet is available for download on the Aptina website.

Comment: @stevenvh They made me sign an NDA :). Edited the question to reflect that.

Answer (score 1):

This can arise through several mechanisms which I'll list.  But there is asome analysis you can do as well.

1) There looks like a vertical line through the image in which it should be a uniform grey (right hand side) plot that single column on a graph and look for patterns.
-> if you see binary count sequences then it's likely the row decoders on chip.
--> "solution" would be to increase by-pass capacitors and try to filter/split power supplies more.

2) If the noise looks less like a count sequence but still has some characteristic frequencies. then it could be Power supply noise.  Look to your how well you power supplies are filtered, how your ground planes are laid out.

--> as an aside, you can run a FFT over that sampled column to see if there are dominant frequencies.

--> knowing the line rate you should be able to calculate the frequency of the aggressor signal.

Comment: I have check the power supplies. 3.3V analog and 3.3V digital. 3.3V has about 10mV noise on it, the 3.3V digital slightly more. There is 100nF on each supply and analog is protected with a ferrite filter.

Comment: I originally forgot to mention, if I reduce the frequency of the clock from FGPA to the imager, things improve massively.

Comment: Added in a comment but post has been updated to reflect that.

Comment: Sensor can give diagonal or some value I set as a test pattern. I looked at the diagonal looked very good. Later I set the pattern to an arbitrary number (2) and checked every pixel and it seems they are all 2. So the problem is on the analog side.

Comment: The test pattern generators are in the digital domain, so you really should get a clean signal regardless of how crappy your supplies are.  the fact that it is mostly row oriented tells yo that it is a slower signal -> means (usually) your power supplies.

Comment: I checked power supplies and even disconnected and fed from an external supply. I will post the images for power supplies.

Comment: You have a global shutter -> unless it's done poorly that means the black level across the whole sensor will bump up and down but there will be no row noise.  In this case, it looks like the column amps and the column ADC's.  One indication of this is is there is any slope to the lines.  If there are purely constrained to one row then the row sampling circuits are what are sampling the noise onto each row.

Comment: What do you mean by slope to the lines? If you look at the image, the lines are across the columns not rows. The image is 90 degree rotated. ie. Sensor is vertically positioned. So the noise is on columns.

Comment: Well, that is IMPORTANT to know!  It's column noise.  You will need to do some calcs.  how large (in DN) are these ripples, what does that mean in voltage domain? and how does that compare to the amplitude of the noise on your power supplies?  You will need cleaner rails than what you have -> I suspect.  the other issue is that if you are driving the FPGA directly that activity can couple back in through your drivers on chip and couple into the power supply.  Grounding of your output drivers on chip will also be important - image current flow will be important too.

Comment: Thanks. A few additional comments, why frequency become a factor? If I reduce the clock frequency the problem goes away. My supply noise is 3mV P2P however during exposure time this goes all the way up to 20mV (perhaps this is the trouble). And the last one, what do you mean by driving FPGA directly.

Comment: Speed?  Many reasons, but principally because at slower speeds the rails recover and are in the flat spot on the trace you show.  the column amplifiers have poor PSRR.  Directly? is you sensor connected to the FPGA or do you drive into a buffer first (which is the recommended way to reduce coupling)

Comment: Ok. Got it. I will see if we can further sanitize the power rails. I don't have a buffer between FPGA and the sensor. Can I do anything on FPGA side to mitigate the issue. (I have designed the board with great care on noise and grounding etc. It come out pretty clean, so I was refusing to believe it is power but I will now do another through check tomorrow, so now I need to see if something can be done on FPGA. I have zero ohms on the data line, should I replace them with 22ohms)

Answer (score 1):

I've noticed similar stripes when powering the analog part of the MT9V032 with a switching regulator and a passive LC filter. You could try to generate the analog supply with a linear regulator with low noise and good PSRR (e.g. TPS79333).

Comment: My circuit already has TPS71701 after the switcher to avoid these problems. It should be clean enough.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have the schematics of the Aptina MT9V032 Camera Board (MT9V032_DEMO_HEAD)? You can see that every supply pin has its 100nF cap with 1uF in parallel, but the PLLVDD pin is erroneously connected to VAA. Check the MT9V034 Board instead.
Ferrites are good for high frequency noise suppression, but they do not work on low frequency noise, they may even increase it.
You could also try a Ripple Blocker, e.g. MIC94300 from Micrel. There are free samples available.
Could you post the camera parts of your schematics and layout?

Comment: Andreas unfortunately I cannot post the schematic and layout but we have 0.1u on all supply pins and 10u at the background for noise suppression. It seems you have specific experience with this IC, we couldn't find the problem so far.

Comment: We suspect the issue is largely due to the mode we are using (snapshot) vs. the general mode (master)